# Python nested lists search optimization

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization, primes

I have a search and test problem :
in the list of prime numbers from 2 to 100k, we're searching the first set of 5 with the following criteria :

- p1 < p2 < p3 < p4 < p5
- any combination of 2 primes from the solution (3 and 7 => 37 and 73) must also be a prime
- sum(p1..p5) is the
  smallest possible sum of primes satisfying criteria, and is above
  100k

I can totally code such a thing, but i have a severe optimization problem : my code is super duper slow. I have a list of primes under 100k, a list of primes over 100k, and a primality test which works well, but i do not see how to optimize that to obtain a result in a correct time.

For a basic idea :

- the list of all primes under 100k contains 9592 items
- the list of all primes under 1 billion contains approximately 51 million lines
- i have the list of all primes under 1 billion, by length

Thanks for the help

Comment: This may be better suited to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) because your code works, it's just slow.

Comment: So the concatenation of any two of the five primes must be prime relative to the sum of the five. Right? Not that the concatenation of the two is prime or that the sum of the five is prime.

Comment: so, this is somewhat difficult to optimise without actual code, but typically if you have numeric data in nested lists, you will be much better off using numpy and its optimised methods.

Comment: Formulation as a graph problem: you're looking for 5-cliques in the graph where vertices are prime numbers below 100k, and two vertices share an edge iff their concatenations are prime numbers.

Comment: you need the primes up to 10E9 to do the test if p4-p5 or p5-p4 is a prime

Comment: Anything like this is going to be slow in Python.  You can expect a speed up of at least 50 times if you port your code to a compiled language ( e.g. C++ ). Would that meet your performance requirement? ( you forgot to say what your performance requirement is! )

Comment: @ravenspoint That's a silly argument. It's quite feasible that a skilled Python programmer could develop code that is functionally identical and superior in performance when compared to its C++ equivalent when the C++ coder is a rank novice

Comment: @Codist I would not assign the coding task to a rank novice.  To use your word, that would be silly.

Comment: If you are looking for mathematical optimization as you have tagged, [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is a better choice.

Comment: What does "super duper slow" mean to you? How long does it take to run?

Comment: @kindall : i take good note

Comment: @JonSG : No, the concatenation of the two primes must be a prime by itself

Comment: @Stef : i'm not used to working with graphs, i'm gonna look into that

Comment: @rioV8 : I thought about that. It depends if p4 is 4 digits or 5 digits. I hope the first solution is small enough. In the meantime, if the number obtained is big, i do a full primality test.

Comment: This question is too broad as currently written. It's also unclear exactly what you're asking. if you have code that works, why isn't that code here in the question? If you have _working_ code and just want it to be improved, consider asking on Code Review or provide specific, measurable metrics by which others can consider the code "improved".

Comment: I do not second the advice to go to codereview. I think they're more about "How can I improve this code with good programming practices" than about "How can I improve this code by switching to a completely different algorithm". In more detail: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Too broad for what purpose? At least one person found the question narrow enough to write an answer, and the OP commented *"your answer was perfect, right on spot"*. Not to mention, several people found both the question and the answer interesting enough to upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) version that computes the minimal combination of the prime numbers with restrictions as stated in the question.

The majority of runtime is spent in pre-computing all valid combinations of prime numbers. On my computer (AMD 5700X) this runs in 1 minute 20 seconds:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange


@njit
def prime(a):
    if a < 2:
        return False
    for x in range(2, int(a**0.5) + 1):
        if a % x == 0:
            return False
    return True


@njit
def str_to_int(s):
    final_index, result = len(s) - 1, 0
    for i, v in enumerate(s):
        result += (ord(v) - 48) * (10 ** (final_index - i))
    return result


@njit
def generate_primes(n):
    out = []
    for i in range(3, n + 1):
        if prime(i):
            out.append(i)
    return out


@njit(parallel=True)
def get_comb(n=100_000):
    # generate all primes < n
    primes = generate_primes(n)
    n_primes = len(primes)

    # generate all valid combinations of primes
    combs = np.zeros((n_primes, n_primes), dtype=np.uint8)

    for i in prange(n_primes):
        for j in prange(i + 1, n_primes):
            p1, p2 = primes[i], primes[j]

            c1 = str_to_int(f"{p1}{p2}")
            c2 = str_to_int(f"{p2}{p1}")

            if not prime(c1) or not prime(c2):
                continue

            combs[i, j] = 1

    all_combs = []

    for i_p1 in prange(0, n_primes):
        for i_p2 in prange(i_p1 + 1, n_primes):
            if combs[i_p1, i_p2] == 0:
                continue
            for i_p3 in prange(i_p2 + 1, n_primes):
                if combs[i_p1, i_p3] == 0:
                    continue
                if combs[i_p2, i_p3] == 0:
                    continue
                for i_p4 in prange(i_p3 + 1, n_primes):
                    if combs[i_p1, i_p4] == 0:
                        continue
                    if combs[i_p2, i_p4] == 0:
                        continue
                    if combs[i_p3, i_p4] == 0:
                        continue
                    for i_p5 in prange(i_p4 + 1, n_primes):
                        if combs[i_p1, i_p5] == 0:
                            continue
                        if combs[i_p2, i_p5] == 0:
                            continue
                        if combs[i_p3, i_p5] == 0:
                            continue
                        if combs[i_p4, i_p5] == 0:
                            continue

                        p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 = (
                            primes[i_p1],
                            primes[i_p2],
                            primes[i_p3],
                            primes[i_p4],
                            primes[i_p5],
                        )

                        ccomb = np.array([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5], dtype=np.int64)
                        if np.sum(ccomb) < n:
                            continue

                        all_combs.append(ccomb)
                        print(ccomb)
                        break

    return all_combs


all_combs = np.array(get_comb())
print()
print("Minimal combination:")
print(all_combs[np.sum(all_combs, axis=1).argmin()])
```

Prints:

```
[    3 28277 44111 70241 78509]
[    7    61 25939 26893 63601]
[    7    61 25939 61417 63601]                     
[    7    61 25939 61471 86959]                     
[    7  2467 24847 55213 92593]                     
[    7  3361 30757 49069 57331]                

...

[ 1993 12823 35911 69691 87697]
[ 2287  4483  6793 27823 67723]
[ 3541  9187 38167 44257 65677]
                                                    
Minimal combination:                                
[   13   829  9091 17929 72739]
                                                    
real    1m20,599s                                   
user    0m0,011s                                    
sys     0m0,008s
```

Comment: your answer was perfect, right on spot, and super fast (just under a minute on a I7). I would definitely look into numba, prange and njit. Thanks a lot !

Comment: `range(2, int(a**0.5) + 1)` why test with all the even numbers in this range, `itertools.chain([2], range(3,int(a**0.5)+1,2))`, or you only have to use the prime numbers you already found that are `<int(a**0.5)+1`

Comment: `def generate_primes(n): return [i for i in range(3, n+1,2) if prime(i)]`